# Generate pdf in HHVM not work

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-5, hhvm, phpwkhtmltopdf

I used nginx and hhvm on my ubuntu server , and `mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf`  package in laravel for generating pdf but generated pdf in HHVM shows content below and in my local machine works good:

[image]

My code is :

```
  $logo = storage_path('logo/logo.jpg');
  $font = storage_path('fonts/IRRoya.ttf');
  $barcode = DNS2D::getBarcodePNG($order["registration_number"], "QRCODE",5,5);
  $date = jDateTime::strftime('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($order['order_date']));
  $f_date = jDateTime::convertNumbers($date);
  $view =   view('bill.bill',compact('order','logo','font','barcode','f_date'));
  $pdf = new Pdf(array(
      'no-outline',
      'margin-top'    => 0,
      'margin-right'  => 0,
      'margin-bottom' => 0,
      'margin-left'   => 0,
      'disable-smart-shrinking',
      'commandOptions' => array(
          'useExec' => true,
          'procEnv' => array(
              'LANG' => 'fa_IR.utf-8',
          ),
      ),
    ));
    $pdf->addPage($view);
    $pdf->send();
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Are you sending the `Content-Type` header correctly?

Comment: `phpwkhtmltopdf ` does not?

Comment: Depends on how you're using it

Comment: updated question i put my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
  $logo = storage_path('logo/logo.jpg');
  $font = storage_path('fonts/IRRoya.ttf');
  $barcode = DNS2D::getBarcodePNG($order["registration_number"], "QRCODE",5,5);
  $date = jDateTime::strftime('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($order['order_date']));
  $f_date = jDateTime::convertNumbers($date);
  $view =   view('bill.bill',compact('order','logo','font','barcode','f_date'));
  $pdf = new Pdf(array(
      'no-outline',
      'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
      'margin-top'    => 0,
      'margin-right'  => 0,
      'margin-bottom' => 0,
      'margin-left'   => 0,
      'disable-smart-shrinking',
      'commandOptions' => array(
          'useExec' => true,
          'procEnv' => array(
              'LANG' => 'fa_IR.utf-8',
          ),
      ),
    ));
    $pdf->addPage($view);
    $content = $pdf->toString();
    return response($content)->withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
            'Pragma' => 'public',
            'Content-disposition' => 'attachment; filename='.$order["registration_number"].'.pdf',
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
            'Content-Length' => strlen($content)
        ]);
```